# ORM in laravel 5.4 not working

Tags: php, database, join, orm, laravel-5.4

I have 2 tables "Items" and "brands". items contains product details such as item_id, name and brand_id while brands contains brandId and brand_name. I want to fetch Item data in which I can join brands and items.

This is my controller.

```
public function filters($id){
    $items = Items::brands();       
    return $items;
}
```

This is my model.

```
public static function brands(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Brands');
}
```

I got the following while running on my browser.
Using $this when not in object context

Comment: you have a static method and you are using $this in it what did you think will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the static keyword

```
public function brand(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Brands','brand_id');
}
```

in your Brands you need

```
public function item(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Items','brandId','brand_id');
}
```

and your controller:

```
public function filters($id){
    $items = Items::all()->with('brands')->get();       
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: I think item `belongsTo` to brand

Comment: Worked fine when I put.
public function brands(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Brands', 'brand_id', 'brand_id');
}

Comment: you should name it `brand` because you have `1:1` 1 item 1 brand,

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

Model File :

```
public function brands(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Brands');
}
```

And controller like this :

```
public function filters($id){
    $items = Items::select("*")->with('brands')->get()->toArray();       
    return $items;
}
```